# why am I getting "string" in the field when I use Query to pass multiple URL inputs?

Tags: python, url, swagger, fastapi

[image: swagger UI]

I'm expecting the field to be empty instead of "string". I tried using `Query(default=None)`.  But unable to get the expected output in the swagger UI.
Here is my code snippet:

```
def Input_Multiple_URLs(mutiple_input_urls: Optional[list[str]] = Query(default=None)):
    #code
```

Answer (score 0):

The default is on the list and not on the items in the list.

So by default the list of "mutiple_input_urls" is empty but once you add item its a str and thats why its value=string

in order to change the default of the item you can change the openapi schema

```
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi

def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema
    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="FastAPI",
        version="0.1.0",
        description="This is a very custom OpenAPI schema",
        routes=app.routes,
    )
    openapi_schema["paths"]["/multiple_Input_URLs"]["post"]["parameters"][0]["schema"]["items"]["default"] = "your default" # can be "" for empty string

    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
    return app.openapi_schema

app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

check the url I wrote (i guessed it cause I am not aware if its under any route)

Comment: Hi, is there any way to resolve it? I don't want to see string in the swagger UI.